# remove text between square brackets

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to remove the text between the square brackets, however it only seems to remove the brackets.

```
SELECT Replace(Replace(aud_desc, '[', ''), ']', '') from _audit
```

`aud_desc` is `This is [a] test` however with the above I have got it to show `This is a test`, I am not sure why its not removing the text in the brackets as well.

Have I missed something?

Comment: because you are only replacing the brackets with space

Comment: replace will replace the part of the string that matches your pattern with the given new string, in your case you've asked it to replace a '[' with '' and then after that replace ']' with a ''

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE`, `LENGTH`, `LOCATE`, `REVERSE` & `SUBSTRING`functions.

```
SELECT REPLACE(aud_desc, SUBSTRING(aud_desc, LOCATE('[', aud_desc), LENGTH(aud_desc) - LOCATE(']', REVERSE(aud_desc)) - LOCATE('[', aud_desc) + 2), '') AS aud_desc
FROM _audit
```

Input:

aud_desc

```
word [brakcet] word
[brakcet] word
word [brakcet]
```

Output:

aud_desc

```
word word
word
word
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/178bb/1/0

Comment: Doesn't work if you have something in brackets twice in the string.

Comment: @jceddy In that case you could use a Loop to run through n times, with n being calculated by the count of [ and ] divided by 2?

Comment: I posted an answer containing a function that handles multiple copies of text in brackets. The solution you posted is greedy, so looping as you suggest won't work, as the very first iteration of the loop will strip out everything from the first opening bracket to the last closing bracket.

Comment: @jceddy Just read your solution, much better and more scale-able than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a user-defined function that does it and works with multiple bracket pairs in the string:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION REMOVE_BRACKETS(input TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin)
  RETURNS TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
  BEGIN
    DECLARE output TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE in_brackets BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE length INT;

    IF(input IS NULL)
    THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    WHILE(TRUE) DO
      SET length = LOCATE(CASE WHEN in_parens THEN ']' ELSE '[' END, input);
      IF(length = 0)
      THEN
        RETURN CONCAT(output, input);
      END IF;

      IF(in_brackets)
      THEN
        SET in_brackets = FALSE;
      ELSE
        SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, 1, length - 1));
        SET in_brackets = TRUE;
      END IF;

      SET input = SUBSTRING(input, length + 1);
    END WHILE;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aud_desc,'[',1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(aud_desc,']',-1)) 
FROM _audit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should not remove text in the brackets at all. All it does - is replaces `[` and `]` characters with empty character, thus removing them.

To remove text in the brackets you can use [locate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function to get position of `[`, then one more time `locate` to get position of `]` and then use [substr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function to get appropriate parts of string according to `[]` symbols positions.

Answer (score 0):

Following https://stackoverflow.com/users/2641576/matt idea, this is the solution for SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(aud_desc, SUBSTRING(aud_desc, CHARINDEX('[', aud_desc), LEN(aud_desc) - CHARINDEX(']', REVERSE(aud_desc)) - CHARINDEX('[', aud_desc) + 2), '')   AS aud_desc
FROM _audit
```